# Derivative of $|x|^\alpha$

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate the derivative of $|x|^\alpha$ with respect to $x$, where $1<\alpha<2$.

$\frac{d|x|^\alpha}{dx}=\alpha|x|^{\alpha-1}\mathrm{sign}(x)$

Is it correct?

And is it true that

$\lim_{x \to 0} \alpha|x|^\alpha\mathrm{sign}(x)=0$?

What with the following derivative $|x|^\alpha\rm{sign}(x)$. I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: Your limit ($\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\alpha |x|^\alpha \operatorname{sign}(x) =0$) is correct, as you can show with the help of the squeeze theorem for example (or just separately take limits as $x\to 0^+$ and $x\to 0^-$).

Comment: You have to compute $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$

Comment: Thank you, but I do not know how to deal with this limit $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|x_0+h|^\alpha-|x_0|^\alpha}{h} $$. We have $\frac{[0]}{[0]}$.

Comment: You may be interested in having a look at this old post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064118/regularity-of-the-function-xax

Comment: It is enough to express your function as $f(x)=\left(\sqrt{x^2}\right)^{\alpha}$ and differentiate it as a composite function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $x_0 > 0$. We can assume that $|h| < x_0$ so that $x_0 + h > 0$. We get
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|x_0+h|^\alpha-|x_0|^\alpha}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(x_0+h)^\alpha-x_0^\alpha}{h} = \alpha x_0^{\alpha-1} = \alpha |x_0|^{\alpha-1}$$
since the latter limit is simply the derivative of $x \mapsto x^\alpha$ at $x_0$.

Similarly, if $x_0 < 0$ and $|h| < -x_0$, we have $x_0 + h < 0$ so
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|x_0+h|^\alpha-|x_0|^\alpha}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(-x_0-h)^\alpha-(-x_0)^\alpha}{h} = -\alpha (-x_0)^{\alpha-1} =-\alpha |x_0|^{\alpha-1}$$
since the latter limit is simply the derivative of $x \mapsto (-x)^\alpha$ at $x_0$.

If $x_0 = 0$, we have

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\left|\frac{|h|^\alpha}{h}\right| = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|h|^\alpha}{|h|} = \lim_{h\to 0} |h|^{\alpha-1} = 0$$
and hence $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|h|^\alpha}{h}=0$.
Putting everything together, we get that the derivative of $x\mapsto |x|^\alpha$ is $x \mapsto \alpha|x|^{\alpha-1}\operatorname{sign}(x)$.

---

Yes, we have $\lim_{x\to 0}\alpha|x|^\alpha\operatorname{sign}(x) = 0$ because
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\big|\alpha|x|^\alpha\operatorname{sign}(x)\big| = \lim_{x\to 0}\alpha|x|^\alpha = 0$$

---

For the function $x \mapsto |x|^\alpha\operatorname{sign}(x)$ we obtain the derivative $x \mapsto \alpha|x|^{\alpha-1}$ similarly as above.

Comment: Is there a way to show that $\lim_{h\to 0} |h|^{\alpha-1} = 0$ without $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$ rule defined for irrational numbers?

Comment: @yellowcat Let $\varepsilon > 0$. For $0 < |h| < \varepsilon^{\frac1{\alpha-1}}$ we have $|h|^{\alpha-1} < \varepsilon.$

Comment: My new question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3718541/735710) was marked as a duplicate of that one, but I'm not quite at the level of being able to prove existence of the things like $\epsilon^{\frac1{\alpha-1}}$ and that $h^\alpha$ is an increasing function.

Comment: @yellowcat Yeah, I have no idea why it was marked as a duplicate since your question clearly asks for a more rigorous/elementary proof. Anyway, the answer you got by zkutch should contain necessary information to define $\varepsilon^{\frac1{a-1}}$ and that $h \mapsto h^\alpha$ is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\mathrm{sign} (x)=2\delta (x)$$
Where $\delta (x)$ is the Dirac delta function. You can reach the required result by using the product rule.

Comment: This would be useful for finding the second derivative of $|x|^\alpha$, but I'm not sure how it relates to what the OP is asking about.

Comment: The OP also asked what the derivative of $|x|^\alpha \mathrm{sign} (x)$ was in the last line.

Comment: Ah, that's what they were asking about there.  I honestly couldn't tell.