# Modulus of x raised to a

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

For what values of $a \in R^+ $ the function $$f(x) = |x|^a$$ is differentiable at $x=0$.
According to definition of differentiablity $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$ should exist & equal for $\lim_{x\to0^+} $and $\lim_{x\to0^-}$ . So according to this the limit for $a≤1$ right & left limits are not equal & for $a≥2$ they are equal but I have doubt for $a\in(1,2)$ this formula gives limit = $0$ for both right & left sides of $0$ but when we plot the graph for $a\in(1,2)$ [there is a steep change in slopes at $x=0$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crrNf.png). How to prove or disprove that it is differentiable at $0$ for $a\in(1,2)$?

Comment: You should use `\in` ($\in$) instead of an epsilon.

Comment: How did you get the conditions you found for the equality or non-equality of the one-sided limits? You should only have a separation at $a = 1$ I believe. See here for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3136205/1104384

Comment: I went through that & I have done the same thing for calculating the both sided limits but my question includes graphical explanation too.. & I think that the graph at $x\lim_{x\to0}$ have a gentle slope that is not visible graphically & but that thing is represented by the calculation of limit of both sides which comes out to be $0$ . ...am I right ?

Comment: @BrunoB the inequality is merely for non existence of derivatives at $x=0$ for $a ≤1 $ but I got your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value of$\lim_{x\to0}$ in the differentiablity test gives $0$ in the interval $a \in(1,2)$. And for existence of derivatives both right & left hand limits should be equal & they are ; hence differentiable in that interval. And the answer to the question for "graphical steep change" in slopes is, the word "$limit$".[image: when we go on zoom & zoom there is a smooth parabola at 0]When we go on zoom & zoom there is a smooth parabola at 0.For convenience I have taken $a=1.8$ and this example is great to visualise the concept of "$limit$" approaching something.